# How do I record my drums onto computer with roland td1kv?

Tags: drums, electronic-drumset, midi-controller-drums

I am using Roland TD1KV electronic drum kit. The manual says that you can easily record your drums and transfer it into a computer using a "standard USB cable", "sold separately". What do they mean by "standard usb cable"? Unfortunately there are no videos of how to connect roland td1kv to your computer.
 This is what the manual says

```
TheTD-1KV is not just fun to play by itself—it’s also a great way to makemusic with your computer. Included is a built-in USB-MIDI interface,making it simple to communicate with music software via just a USBcable, with no extra hardware needed. Maybe you’ll transfer your playinginto your computer-b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a USB cable and some recording software. 
There are several different types of USB cables as seen here [image: USB connection types]

It looks to me that you need a type B on the drum end most likely a type A on the computer end. [image]

Then you will need a midi capable recording program such as pro tools, finale, reason, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I use ubunut. Any midi capable program available on ubuntu?

Comment: I now use Ardour